# Touchscreen Sniper

Tags: sensor, proximity-sensor, capacitive

I was reading today about how capacitive touch works.  [This article](http://playground.arduino.cc/Main/CapacitiveSensor) on the Arduino site mentions that with a 40 Megaohm resistor you could detect an untouched "touch" from possibly 24 inches away.

My question is, can this be focused to a point on a touchscreen?  Would it be possible to build a device that could manipulate someone's phone from two or more feet away?

EDIT: Is it possible to have an extremely directional device that works like a capacitor that is directed at a smartphone screen which would cause the smartphone to trigger a touch.  Could this device work at a distance of 24 inches or more.

Comment: Bwuahahahahah! Remote phone control!!! Er, no! I guess if you can't tell the difference between 40\$\Omega\$ and 40M\$\Omega\$, you can't tell the difference between sensing an effect with an Arduino library, and creating a phone touch ray to give you god-like phone hacking powers!

Comment: Bah. That totally was a typo.

Comment: Um, that resistor would be in the phone (I'm pretty sure they use a different approach), so I'm not quite sure how the linked article has anything to do with manipulating a touch screen remotely.

Comment: A phone has issues registering a direct touch, let alone a gloved touch sometimes. While it's not impossible to remotely activate a touch screen from an inch or two, 2 feet is improbable and AFAIK not yet done.